# How to design separate features Laravel app?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

If I have a data model User and another one represents a Post, these two models together represent the core of the bussiness logic, a Social app where the central players here are the Post and the User. And I have multiple models releated to both the User, and the Post. And they represent features in the bussiness logic, for instance there's a Comment Model (It's a relation between Post and User), and I have an Interaction relation where a user can like a post or not.

I want to build an app that has the core bussiness logic (here the Post and Usre) and the features of it may be added or not. or Sometimes I want to add some and some not.

For instance, I'd like to use the app without a post can have a comment. So I want the process of adding and removing these features to be as easy as possible.

The Problem is I can't separate the features out the core logic. For instance, when I try to get the data of model , surely some data of the other models will be included, this makes it hard to eleiminate these features in future.

So in Post repository I might have the following code:

```
  $postResponse = Post::where('id', $post_id);
  $postResponse->Comments = Post->comments()->where('user_id', $user_id);

  // and so on ...
```

If I wanted to remove feature 'Comment' and all its releated data, this will be a tremendous job.

I'm wondering what's the best pattern to follow in this case? I've just read about SOLID Princples but I can't apply them in this case, for example how to apply the Single Responsibilty Principle to separate data fetching and compining them altogether?

Comment: anyone can help?

Comment: Sounds like you want Feature Flags of some sort.

Comment: Sounds like a solution, I don't know much about Feature Flags but that's supposed to fill my code with conditions (turn on/off a feature) right?

Comment: Query for Laravel Feature Flags, it should make immediate sense. Note they're usually meant to embargo coded features for CI/CD and A/B rollouts, not necessarily component-level functionality box-outs.